# Como utilizar o "LIKE" do SQL no Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize-js

Estou desenvolvendo utilizando sequelize mas como é minha primeira vez utilizando esta ORM estou com algumas duvidas.

Tenho o código abaixo para fazer um consulta no banco de dados através de um input tipo text porém estou utilizando o atributo no where que se refere ao igual e gostaria de um que seria o contenha ou seja verificar se alguma das informações no input de busca contem no campo username.

O meu codigo atual é este:

```
User.findAll({ where: { US_USERNAME: req.query.search } }).then(users => {
                            res.render('main/users', {
                                title: "Usuarios",
                                usuario: users,
                            });
                        });
```

Eu gostaria de trocar o igual do where por um like para verificar se a palavra consultada em `req.query.search }` contém no campo de username do meu banco e não se é igual. Resumindo quero trocar o igual do where por um like no sequelize

Comment: Já tentou `User.findAll({ where: {US_USERNAME: {[Op.like]: "%" + req.query.search}} })` ?

Comment: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#-findall-search-for-multiple-elements-in-the-database

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você pode usar o operador `Op.like` do Sequelize para fazer consultas que usem o `LIKE` dos bancos SQL.

```js
const { Op } = Sequelize;              // biblioteca de operadores
const query = `%${req.query.search}`;  // string de consulta

User.findAll({ where: { US_USERNAME: { [Op.like]: query } } })
  .then(users => {
    res.render('main/users', {
      title: "Usuarios",
      usuario: users,
    });
  });
```

Por exemplo, imagine um valor para `req.query.search = 'andre'`, teríamos a query:

```
query = '%andre'
```

isso irá fazer uma consulta no banco do tipo:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE us_username LIKE '%andre';
```

```js
User.findAll({ where: { US_USERNAME: { [Op.like]: '%andre' } } })
  .then(users => {
    res.render('main/users', {
      title: "Usuarios",
      usuario: users,
    });
  });
```

Veja mais aqui: [Operators no Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators)